# Laravel 5 Remove pages, that generate by Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

We have a review page which get data from DB to show list of reviews by using this

```
$reviews = Review::latest('created_at')->paginate(5);
```

And we have pages navigator at the bottom of the page which auto generate by Laravel. Everything working fine. we can go to see old reviews by use url like this

```
/reviews/?page=10
```

We keep adding new reviews to database until we found out, these data are  making negative effect to SEO, then we decided to remove all reviews pages except the first one which still need to list latest 10 reviews from database.

I also remove the pages navigator, then user can not click through those links.

But the problem is, the url `/reviews/?page=10` still exist, is possible to remove all old review pages or at least redirect them to `/reviews/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can redirect with status 301 with the `Redirect` Facade:

```
return Redirect::to('/reviews', 301);
```

Comment: Where should I put this? I tried at routes `Route::get('reviews/{page}' , function(){return Redirect::to('/reviews', 301);) }` but didn't work :(

Comment: Its hard to say where you should put it without seeing your controller and routes file